# Reading Properties file inside conf folder

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception

I have a properties file which is located under conf folder. conf folder is under the project root directory. I am using the following code.

```
public class PropertiesTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream inputStream = PropertiesTest.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/conf/sampleprop.conf");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("TEST"));
}
}
```

But I get nullpointer exception.

I have tried using

```
InputStream inputStream = PropertiesTest.class
        .getResourceAsStream("./conf/sampleprop.conf");
```

and

```
InputStream inputStream = PropertiesTest.class
        .getResourceAsStream("conf/sampleprop.conf");
```

But all result in nullpointer exception.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you do us a little ASCII-art diagram showing where this source file lives in relation to the conf folder?

Comment: <project folder>
|__src
|
|__conf
      |
      |__sampleprop.conf

Comment: and where is your PropertiesTest class/

Comment: @user1407668 Try using absolute path.

Comment: @user1407668 Try this  PropertiesTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf/sampleprop.conf");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getResourceAsStream()` method tries to locate and load the resource using the ClassLoader of the class it is called on. Ideally it can locate the files only the class folders .. Rather you could use `FileInputStream` with relative path.

**EDIT**

if the `conf` folder is under src, then you still be able to access with `getResourceAsStream()`

```
 InputStream inputStream = Test.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("../conf/sampleprop.conf");
```

the path would be relative to the class from you invoke `getRes..` method.

If not

```
 try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("conf/sampleprop.conf");
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(fis);
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("TEST"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

NOTE: this will only work if it is Stand alone application/in eclipse. This will not work if its web based (as the root will be Tomcat/bin, for eg)

I would suggest to copy the configuration file at designated place, then you can acess at ease. At certain extent 'System.getProperty("user.dir")' can be used if you are always copying the file 'tomcat` root or application root.  But if the files to be used by external party, ideal to copy in a configurable folder (C:\appconf)

Comment: its not under src.... Both conf and src are in the same level under project folder

Comment: This worked fine....As mine is a standalone application running continously, this would do the job... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to recover your working directory first:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Current working dir: " + workingDir);
```

and then is simple:

```
Properties propertiesFile = new Properties();
propertiesFile.load(new FileInputStream(workingDir+ "/yourFilePath"));
    String first= propertiesFile.getProperty("myprop.first");
```

Regards, fabio

Answer (score 0):

Your code works like a charm! But you might have to add the project root dir to your classpath.

If you work with Maven, place your configuration in src/main/resources/conf/sampleprop.conf

When invoking java directly add the project root dir with the java -classpath parameter. Something like:

```
java -classpath /my/classes/dir:/my/project/root/dir my.Main
```